# Seer torshi (pickled garlic) with metal lids dissolved in the vinegar

Tags: food-safety, pickling

So I pickled a lot of garlic 8 years ago, but being a novice, did not know the metallic lids would dissolve due to the vinegar.

The garlic is whole, still in its husks, and I was wondering if it were safe to eat?

Answer (score 1):

Proper canning lids are coated and don't normally rust through if undamaged and not wetted on the outside. Acid contents are completely normal and expected in canning.

8 years old - sitting open for unknown time since lids rusted through - toss it.

Comment: The lids aren't open, just some fraction of them dissolved in the vinegar. The vinegar is 7%+ (I remember going a little mad and getting Jerez vinegar). The garlic is kept submerged in it, is not green or bad smelling, so should be ok other than my question about the metal issue! (Seer torshi is pickled for decades also, so the age is not an issue, just the metal..), thanks for the reply also!